# PyQT5 открытие/закрытие окна по триггеру

Tags: python, ооп, многопоточность, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты

Программа все время работает в фоне и показывает/скрывает окно по определенным системным событиям.

Вот код окна:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.addStretch(-1)
        self.setMinimumSize(550, 227)

        self.btnOk = QPushButton(self)
        self.btnOk.move(230,90)
        self.btnOk.resize(260,30)
        self.btnOk.setText("Закрыть")
        self.btnOk.clicked.connect(self.btn_click)

    def btn_click(self):
        print("Закрываю")
        self.close()
```

Теперь необходимо сделать так, чтобы это окно могло появиться и исчезнуть по определенному событию.

Когда необходимо произвести событие "открытия" я делаю вот так:

```
window = QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = MainWindow()
mw.show()
window.exec_()
```

Окно открывается и содержит кнопку нажав на которую это окно закрывается.
Теперь хочу сделать, чтобы это окно могло автоматически закрыться по другому событию.

Пытаюсь выполнить:

```
MainWindow().btn_click()
```

В терминале появляется текст "Закрываю" но ничего не происходит. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. У программы окно скрыто до определенного момента...

`QWidget::show()` - показывает виджет и его дочерние виджеты.

> 2. Теперь необходимо сделать так, чтобы это окно могло появиться и исчезнуть по определенному событию.

Вы можете использовать статическую функцию `QTimer::singleShot()` 
для вызова слота после указанного интервала.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.addStretch(-1)
        self.setMinimumSize(550, 227)

        self.btnOk = QPushButton(self)
        self.btnOk.move(230,90)
        self.btnOk.resize(260,30)
        self.btnOk.setText("Закрыть")
        self.btnOk.clicked.connect(self.btn_click)

        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.btnOk.click)             # <---

    def btn_click(self):
        print("Закрываю")
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    window = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    window.exec_()
```

---

**Update**

Вы уточнили, что ваша **программа многопоточная**, 
но ваш пример даже приблизительно не демонстрирует это.
С целью экономии вашего и чужого времени и получения 
быстрых и правильных ответов (которые решают вашу проблему),
вы должны публиковать минимально-воспроизводимый пример,
который собственно говоря демонстрирует проблему.

Я попробую еще раз помочь вам и показать принцип работы 
и обработки потоковых данных.

Предлагаемый пример состоит из главного окна (Gui) 
из которого можно запустить **две потоковые задачи**,
нажав на соответствующие кнопки `Start поток WorkThread` и `Запустить поток WorkThreadMain`.

Задача `WorkThreadMain` - не имеет собственного окна, а результаты ее работы отображаются в основном GUI.

Задача `WorkThread` - **ИМЕЕТ** собственное окно, отображая в нем данные,
а результаты ее работы также отображаются в основном GUI.
В окне этой задачи имеется кнопка `Close поток WorkThread`, 
но она сработает только если поток остановлен (мне так захотелось).

> Теперь необходимо сделать так, чтобы это окно могло появиться и исчезнуть по определенному событию.

**Событие открытия** окна задачи `WorkThread` - нажатие  кнопки `Start поток WorkThread`

**Событие закрытия** окна задачи `WorkThread`:

```
- нажатие кнопки `Stop поток WorkThread` в основном окне;

- результат работы этой задачи равен 99 (см. метод run в классе WorkThread).
```

Я предполагаю, что это то, что вам надо.

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
import random

class WorkThread(Qt.QThread):
    ''' Потоковая задача WorkThread со своим окном. '''

    threadSignal = Qt.pyqtSignal(int)     

    def __init__(self, startParm):
        super().__init__()
        self.startParm = startParm

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        while self.startParm != 99:
            Qt.QThread.msleep(200)
            self.startParm += 1
            # Излючаем сигнал и передаем аргументы подключенному слоту
            self.threadSignal.emit(self.startParm)   


class WorkThreadMain(Qt.QThread):
    ''' Потоковая задача WorkThreadMain без своего окна. '''

    threadSignalMain = Qt.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, startParm):
        super().__init__()
        self.startParm = startParm

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            Qt.QThread.msleep(1000)
            self.startParm += 1
            self.threadSignalMain.emit(self.startParm)


class MsgBox(Qt.QDialog):
    """ Класс инициализации окна для визуализации потока WorkThread
        и кнопка для закрытия потокового окна, если поток остановлен! """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(900, 65, 400, 80)
        self.setWindowTitle('MsgBox для WorkThread')

        self.label = Qt.QLabel("")
        self.close_btn = Qt.QPushButton("Close поток WorkThread")
        # закроет окно, если поток остановлен
        self.close_btn.clicked.connect(self.close)        

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.close_btn)


class MainWindow(Qt.QWidget):    
    ''' Главное окно. В методе __init__:
    - объявили все виджеты, установили валидацию    
    - привязали нажатие кнопок к сигналам для вызова нужных слотов 
    - создали экземпляр дополнительного окна '''

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(540, 65, 320, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow')

        self.labelMain = Qt.QLabel("Результат потоковой задачи WorkThreadMain: ")
        self.labelThread = Qt.QLabel("Результат Потоковой задачи WorkThread: ")
        validator = Qt.QIntValidator(1, 999, self)
        validator.setBottom(1)
        self.lineEdit = Qt.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Начильный параметр для потоковой задачи WorkThread")
        # self.lineEdit будет принимать только целые числа от 1 до 999 
        self.lineEdit.setValidator(validator)    
        self.btn = Qt.QPushButton("Start поток WorkThread")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.on_btn)
        self.btnMain = Qt.QPushButton("Запустить поток WorkThreadMain")
        self.btnMain.clicked.connect(self.on_btnMain)

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self) 
        layout.addWidget(self.labelMain)
        layout.addWidget(self.labelThread)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.btnMain)

        self.msg = MsgBox()  
        self.thread     = None
        self.threadMain = None  

    def on_btn(self):
        ''' Запуск или Останов дополнительного Потока-WorkThread из главнонго окна '''

        # Входные параметры для передачи в поток, если не заданы, то передаем дефолтные `0`
        startParm = int(self.lineEdit.text()) if self.lineEdit.text() else 0 

        if self.thread is None:                     
            self.thread = WorkThread(startParm)     # Создаем поток, передакм параметры
            self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.on_threadSignal)
            # Этот сигнал испускается из связанного потока непосредственно перед его завершением.
            self.thread.finished.connect(self.onFinished)  
            self.thread.start()                            # Стартуем поток

            self.btn.setText("Stop поток WorkThread")      # Меняем название кнопки
            self.lineEdit.hide()                           # Прячем виджет ввода пареметров
        else:
            self.thread.terminate()                        # Завершает выполнение потока
            self.thread = None
            self.btn.setText("Start поток WorkThread")
            self.lineEdit.show()

    def onFinished(self):
        print('close_btn.click()')
        self.msg.close_btn.click()
        self.thread = None
        self.btn.setText("Start поток WorkThread")
        self.lineEdit.show()

    def on_threadSignal(self, value):
        ''' Визуализация потоковых данных-WorkThread в основном окне. '''

        self.msg.label.setText(str(value))
        self.labelThread.setText("Результат Потоковой задачи WorkThread: {}".format(str(value)))

        # Восстанавливаем визуализацию потокового окна, если его закрыли. Поток работает.
        if not self.msg.isVisible():        
            self.msg.show()

    def on_btnMain(self):
        ''' Запуск или Останов Потока-WorkThreadMain '''

        cM = random.randrange(1, 100)
        if self.threadMain is None:
            self.threadMain = WorkThreadMain(cM)
            self.threadMain.threadSignalMain.connect(self.on_threadSignalMain)
            self.threadMain.start()
            self.btnMain.setText("Стоп поток WorkThreadMain")
        else:
            self.threadMain.terminate()         
            self.threadMain = None
            self.btnMain.setText("Старт поток WorkThreadMain")

    def on_threadSignalMain(self, value):
        ''' Визуализация потоковых данных WorkThreadMain в основном окне. '''

        self.labelMain.setText("Результат потоковой задачи WorkThreadMain: " + str(value)) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw  = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: QTimer не подходит. Окно должно появляться когда происходит определенное событие в системе. Так же должно пропадать когда происходит другое системное событие.

Comment: @ДанилКучеров   Я вас не понял, `QTimer.singleShot()` это например. Поставьте вместо этого ваше `определенное событие`, которое вызывает `self.btnOk.click()`

Comment: @ДанилКучеров я добавил обновленный ответ.